# unable to store row elements of a dataset, via mapPartitions(), in variables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a Spark Dataset, and then using mapPartitions, trying to access each of its elements and store those in variables. Using below piece of code for the same:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val df = spark.sql("select col1,col2,col3 from table limit 10")

val schema = StructType(Seq(
              StructField("col1", StringType),
              StructField("col2", StringType),
              StructField("col3", StringType)))

val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)

df.mapPartitions{iterator => { val myList = iterator.toList
                 myList.map(x=> { val value1 = x.getString(0)
                                  val value2 = x.getString(1)
                                  val value3 = x.getString(2)}).iterator}} (encoder)
```

The error I am getting against this code is:

```
<console>:39: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Unit]
 val value3 = x.getString(2)}).iterator}} (encoder)
```

Eventually, I am targeting to store the row elements in variables, and perform some operation with these. Not sure what am I missing here. Any help towards this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are several problems with your code:

1. Your map-statement has no return value, therefore `Unit`
2. If you return a tuple of String from mapPartitions, you don't need a `RowEncoder` (because you don't return a `Row`, but a `Tuple3` which does not need a encoder because its a `Product`)

You can write your code like this:

```
df
 .mapPartitions{itr => itr.map(x=> (x.getString(0),x.getString(1),x.getString(2)))}
 .toDF("col1","col2","col3") // Convert Dataset to Dataframe, get desired field names
```

But you could just use a simple `select` statement in DataFrame API, no need for `mapPartitions` here

```
df
.select($"col1",$"col2",$"col3")
```

Comment: @Rapheal Roth , thanks for answering. I tried using the logic you shared. To clarify, I have 592 columns in the table which I am trying to map, and eventually when I am accessing each element from that. Hence getting error :

**too many elements for tuple: 592, allowed: 22**

Modified code:

`df .mapPartitions{itr => itr.map(x=> (x.getString(0),x.getString(1),x.getString(2),x.getString(n)))}
 .toDF("col1","col2","col3","coln").foreach(value => { val variable1=value.getString(0),
 val variable2=value.getString(1),
 val variable3=value.getString(2),
 val variablen=value.getString(n)) `

Comment: Additionally, I am using mapPartitions() with the motive of achieving maximum parallelism, therefore trying to push the logic to executors.